# SQL trigger with joins to send email notification

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am looking to run an insert trigger on a table each time a record is created and send an email notification when the particular critereia comes up that I am looking for. The criteria though is based on a join to another table. How would I set this up with an insert trigger?

Here is the query that I need to run when a record is created in the callforservice table:

```
SELECT dbo.CallForService.CreateDateTime, dbo.CallForService.CommonName, 
dbo.CallLog.Description
FROM dbo.CallForService LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.CallLog ON dbo.CallForService.CFSID = dbo.CallLog.CFSID
WHERE(dbo.CallForService.CallTypeID = 80) and description like %ABL%'
```

I will then be emailing those 3 fields out with sql mail.

How would I go about setting this up?

Comment: I'd avoid sending an email as part of the trigger. Put the data elsewhere, for example a log table, and then use that to send emails. Otherwise, if the email fails to send, your WHOLE transaction is rolled back (so the `INSERT` wouldn't happen).

Comment: Why don't you queue up the notifications somewhere and let another process better equipped to handle the job process the queue. Putting this in a trigger is not recommended.

Comment: Guys you are making a whole lot of sense right now. I did not know that about the transaction role back. How would I do the insert on this data to another table?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of solutions to this one, however, like we've said in the comments, using a `TRIGGER` to send an email is a poor idea. This means that anyone that could cause the trigger to fire will need permissions to use `sp_send_dbmail` and also have access to use the specific profile that you're sending the email from.

Also, should the email fail to send, for whatever reason (maybe your Mail Server is down, or doesn't respond in a timely manner), then the transaction will be rolled back. This means any `INSERT`, `UPDATE` (what ever caused the trigger to fire) will be rolled back as well, and an error will returned the the user/application.

My personal preference would be to use a log table to store details of the records you have emailed (no trigger at all). Have a process email the details of of the relevant records and log the IDs of those records off. You might need to use a `CURSOR` to do this, if you need to send an individual email for each record, but that isn't a bad thing here. This, actually, is what cursors are for.

This is PSEUDO T-SQL, however, should give you an idea of the process you might want to do.

```
--DECLARE CURSOR
DECLARE CallLog_email CURSOR FOR
SELECT [RelevantColumns] --you'll need to put all the columns you need here
FROM dbo.CallForService CFS
WHERE CFS.CallTypeID = 80
  AND CFS.[description] like '%ABL%'
  AND CFS.[ID COLUMN] NOT IN (SELECT sq.[ID COLUMN]
                              FROM dbo.CallForService_EmailLog sq); --This table won't exist at the moment

OPEN CallLog_email;

FETCH NEXT FROM CallLog_email
INTO @ID, @Email, @Name, @OtherVariablesYouNeed; --Again, you'll need variables for your relevant columns

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    --Send email to person(s). This is your email process here.

    INSERT INTO dbo.CallForService_EmailLog ([ID COLUMN], TimeEmailed)
    VALUES (@ID, GETDATE());

    FETCH NEXT FROM CallLog_email
    INTO @ID, @Email, @Name, @OtherVariablesYouNeed;

END

CLOSE CallLog_email;
DEALLOCATE CallLog_email;
```

If you're going to be sending all the data in a tabular format, then there's no need for a `CURSOR`; I was very much guessing what your needs might be. You'd still need to log to the other table.

The other method would be to insert the data into your Log table prior, via a trigger, and then update those rows once you email them; but this method seems cleaner, as triggers can cause more problems than they solve (if designed poorly).

Comment: Thank you for this information. I am going to do some testing with this. So is the above method called a log table? Or is this a stored procedure or something. I'm not that familiar with SQL server and wasn't sure how to set this up.

Comment: The SQL above is incomplete, as I don't have enough information about your set up, or goal, to provide a complete solution (nor would I anyway, as that's a lot of work!). The object `CallLog_email`is a `CURSOR`, which is an iterative object in SQL Server. These are normally frowned upon, but they have their uses (in the right place). i don't know if it's needed here, but offered a more complete answer. `CallForService_EmailLog` is a table, that I "made up" which is effectively a log table of IDs that have been emailed. You'll need to do the work for your actual environment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Setting this up on my test server I have it working and logging the data in the callforservice_emaillog table when I manually run it. How do I run this automatically when new records are inserted in the callforservice table?

Comment: You could put the SQL in an SP, and then use Agent, and set it to a frequent schedule.